# Check which desktop enviroment is the user using (Linux) in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, unity-game-engine, menubar

is it possible to check which desktop environment is the user is using (say KDE or Unity).
The issue is that I have a window which has a menubar, but depending on the desktop environment, the menu is drawn on it or not (for example, in Unity, the menubar is drawn on the panel).
I know that I could just disable the nativeMenuBar feature, but I would prefer to have it enabled.
In my case, I cannot use layouts, so the only two options are to check the desktop enviroment or disable the nativeMenuBar feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the DESKTOP_SESSION environment variable. Use getenv() to do that.